# I can't install any npm

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-lightbox@0.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-icons/all-files@4.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-icons/all-files
npm ERR!     @react-icons/all-files@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"^14.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer next@">= 13.2.5" from next-translate@2.6.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/next-translate
npm ERR!       next-translate@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (react-dom, react-icon, react-icons, styled-jsx, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.12.2 || ^0.13.1" from react-lightbox@0.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-lightbox
npm ERR!   react-lightbox@"^0.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@0.13.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-lightbox
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially brokejectn) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!                                              y
npm ERR!                                              ps
npm ERR! For a full report see:                       n) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! C:\Users\TEBA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-16T13_53_35_454Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C
```

try inst update in react
and inst forece

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This question does not follow any of the recommendations except showing the error message. If you read the error, you can see that react-lightbox is looking for an ancient version of react (^0.12.2 || ^0.13.3) that isn't met by the more modern version your project is specifying (^18.2.0). Sound like you need a new version of react-lightbox or find a new component that was updated in the last decade.

Comment: The problem is react-lightbox. The latest version 0.4.0 from 9 years ago and requires an ancient version of React.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by deleting the `node_modules` folder.

Then run this command:

```
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```